# Graph traversal, maybe another type of mathematics?

Tags: python, algorithm, set, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Let’s say you have a set/list/collection of numbers: [1,3,7,13,21,19] (the order does not matter). Let’s say for reasons that are not important, you run them through a function and receive the following pairs:
(1, 13), (1, 19), (1, 21), (3,19), (7, 3), (7,13), (7,19), (21, 13), (21,19). Again order does not matter. My question involves the next part: how do I find out the minimum amount of numbers that can be part of a pair without being repeated? For this particular sequence it is all six. For [1,4,2] the pairs are (1,4), (1,2), (2,4). In this case any one of the numbers could be excluded as they are all in pairs, but they each repeat, therefore it would be 2 (which 2 do not matter). 
At first glance this seems like a graph traversal problem - the numbers are nodes, the pairs edges. Is there some part of mathematics that deals with this? I have no problem writing up a traversal algorithm, I was just wondering if there was a solution with a lower time complexity. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "being part of a pair without being repeated"?

Comment: Well, isn't the minimum always 0? Didn't you mean 'maximum amount'?

Comment: math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination python: "from itertools import combinations" Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics for the general field. Just finding the count is a simple calculation, using factorial.

Comment: Yeah I think I reversed what was intended.  It could be written 'which combination of pairs would maximize the amount of elements in pairs', or rather 'which combination results in the fewest possible elements not included in pairs'.  That's what I get for writing a question at while at dinner.

Comment: wow, I completely misunderstood the question

Comment: one method I was thinking of doing was generating all possible permutations of points and finding the permutation or permutations with the maximum amount of elements represented, which is in a way a kind of graph traversal.

Answer (score 0):

If you really intended to find the minimum amount, the answer is 0, because you don't have to use any number at all.

I guess you meant to write "maximal amount of numbers".

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like we can translated it to the following problem:
*Given a set of n numbers (1,..,n), what is the maximal amount of numbers I can use to divide the set into pairs, where each number can appear only once.*

The answer to this question is:

- when n = 2k    f(n) = 2k for k>=0
- when n = 2k+1  f(n) = 2k for k>=0

I'll explain, using induction.

1. if n = 0 then we can use at most 0 numbers to create pairs.
2. if n = 2 (the set can be [1,2]) then we can use both numbers to
   create one pair (1,2)
3. Assumption: if n=2k lets assume we can use all 2k numbers to create 2k pairs and prove using induction that we can use 2k+2 numbers for n = 2k+2.
4. Proof: if n = 2k+2, [1,2,..,k,..,2k,2k+1,2k+2], we can create k pairs using 2k numbers (from our assomption). without loss of generality, lets assume out pairs are (1,2),(3,4),..,(2k-1,2k). we can see that we still have two numbers [2k+1, 2k+2] that we didn't use, and therefor we can create a pair out of two of them, which means that we used 2k+2 numbers.

You can prove on your own the case when n is odd.

Comment: Yeah as I commented above I botched the explanation.  It could be written 'which combination of pairs would maximize the amount of elements in pairs', or rather 'which combination results in the fewest possible elements not included in pairs', though in this case the pairs are essentially immutable and the 'edges' between 'nodes' matter.  I'm not sure if this still applies in that case.

Comment: well, if you phrase your question like that, then my solution is incorrect.
For instance, lets say we have the following set: [1,2,3,4,5,6] with the following edges: (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6).
In this case we can use at most 4 numbers (for example 1,2,3,4).

Comment: Correct. As far as I can tell this is at least np hard, maybe np complete. I have a solution that iterates through each combination of pairs (this particular example requires 3 pairs, some may be longer or shorter depending on the length of the set of input integers that generate the pairs) but it’s slow. Is this considered combinatorics? Set theory?  Is there a simple formula relating to the number of pairs or elements? I really have no idea where to look to find a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares in the future, the solution is called a blossom algorithm.